# Access Violation When Opening Project Options

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I am using RADStudio 10 Seattle Update 1 on Windows 10 x64. I am getting an Access Violation intermittently when opening the Project Options (by right-clicking on the project, then selecting Options). I have Googled for a solution several times but have found none.

I have tried:

- Disabling DEP
- Restarting the IDE

  - this resolves the immediate error, and after it starts back up I can access the Project Options again, at least until the next time it happens.
- Recreating the `project.dproj` by renaming and double-clicking the project.dpr to recreate
- Uninstalling all third party components
- Uninstalling the IDE completely, restarting the computer, and re-installing the IDE

None of these solutions seem to help. This is not happening on any specific project. It has happened to every single project I have worked on (since XE6) at least once. The problem is shared by my coworkers.

[image: error_message]

It took an hour to be able to finally get this screen shot after I started writing this post. Nothing unusual happened. I was looking through the suggested articles to make sure I hadn't overlooked something, and when I went back to the IDE and tried to go into the Project Options it happened. I must have tried 20 times over the past hour to make it happen.

Even though this is just a nusance and I can work around it, if there is a permanent solution I would love to fix this for good.

**EDIT**

Just noticed the "Details>>".

```
[2137C817]{vclide230.bpl} PropBox.TPropItem.GetPropName (Line 344, "PropBox.pas" + 1) + $5
[509BAC62]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.GetItemData (Line 6523, "Vcl.StdCtrls.pas" + 1) + $10
[2137C847]{vclide230.bpl} PropBox.TPropItem.GetPropPath (Line 351, "PropBox.pas" + 1) + $4
[2137CE84]{vclide230.bpl} PropBox.TCustomPropListBox.GetPropItem (Line 545, "PropBox.pas" + 4) + $A
[2137EC23]{vclide230.bpl} PropBox.TCustomPropListBox.SetSelectedPropertyPath (Line 1385, "PropBox.pas" + 6) + $B
[205BAAFC]{coreide230.bpl} TaskOptionsPage.TOptionGroupPage.SelectOption (Line 404, "TaskOptionsPage.pas" + 20) + $5
[509FCBD2]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.MakeVisible (Line 9353, "Vcl.ComCtrls.pas" + 2) + $15
[205BD185]{coreide230.bpl} ProjOptDlg.TProjectOptionsDialog.DoFocusControl (Line 341, "ProjOptDlg.pas" + 2) + $4
[207E6769]{coreide230.bpl} BaseOptionsFrm.TBaseOptionsForm.FormShow (Line 390, "BaseOptionsFrm.pas" + 54) + $C
[205BD20F]{coreide230.bpl} ProjOptDlg.TProjectOptionsDialog.FormShow (Line 371, "ProjOptDlg.pas" + 0) + $3
[50AD2A71]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.DoShow (Line 4046, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $14
[50AD727D]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CMShowingChanged (Line 6764, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 11) + $7
[211751B5]{designide230.bpl} DeskForm.TDesktopForm.CMShowingChanged (Line 816, "DeskForm.pas" + 1) + $0
[509931FD]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7249, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[50999F05]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CMShowingChanged (Line 11526, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 0) + $21
[509931FD]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7249, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[50997D3D]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10079, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 158) + $6
[50067E67]{rtl230.bpl  } System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars (Line 39003, "System.pas" + 1) + $F
[50067B37]{rtl230.bpl  } System.UTF8ToUnicodeString (Line 37904, "System.pas" + 11) + $5
[50AD3514]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc (Line 4459, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 206) + $5
[50067B7E]{rtl230.bpl  } System.UTF8ToString (Line 37914, "System.pas" + 1) + $4
[5005F4AD]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TObject.ClassName (Line 16135, "System.pas" + 1) + $7
[50992E38]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform (Line 7027, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 10) + $8
[50997105]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.UpdateShowing (Line 9709, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 19) + $C
[50997214]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.UpdateControlState (Line 9744, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 21) + $3
[50999EDA]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CMVisibleChanged (Line 11517, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $2
[509931FD]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7249, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[50997D3D]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10079, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 158) + $6
[50067E67]{rtl230.bpl  } System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars (Line 39003, "System.pas" + 1) + $F
[50067B37]{rtl230.bpl  } System.UTF8ToUnicodeString (Line 37904, "System.pas" + 11) + $5
[50AD3514]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc (Line 4459, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 206) + $5
[50067B7E]{rtl230.bpl  } System.UTF8ToString (Line 37914, "System.pas" + 1) + $4
[5005F4AD]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TObject.ClassName (Line 16135, "System.pas" + 1) + $7
[50992E38]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform (Line 7027, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 10) + $8
[509917BA]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.SetVisible (Line 6053, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 5) + $C
[50AD2D4D]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.SetVisible (Line 4174, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 9) + $4
[50AD7E37]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Show (Line 7144, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50AD8090]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.ShowModal (Line 7213, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 28) + $3
[21E6CFE4]{delphicoreide230.bpl} BasePasProjOpts.TProjOptsManager.InternalEdit (Line 1205, "BasePasProjOpts.pas" + 130) + $5
[21E6B807]{delphicoreide230.bpl} BasePasProjOpts.TProjOptsManager.Edit (Line 851, "BasePasProjOpts.pas" + 36) + $E
[21E70B3E]{delphicoreide230.bpl} BasePasProjOpts.TProjectOptions.Edit (Line 2286, "BasePasProjOpts.pas" + 1) + $7
[2060F343]{coreide230.bpl} ProjectModule.TBaseProject.ImGivinItAllShesGot (Line 1414, "ProjectModule.pas" + 4) + $F
[500FDF6D]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Rtti.RawInvoke (Line 7479, "System.Rtti.pas" + 44) + $2
[500FE36F]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Rtti.Invoke (Line 7703, "System.Rtti.pas" + 79) + $2
[500F525A]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Rtti.TRttiInstanceMethodEx.DispatchInvoke (Line 5655, "System.Rtti.pas" + 101) + $1C
[500FE804]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Rtti.TRttiMethod.Invoke (Line 8623, "System.Rtti.pas" + 1) + $D
[2060EAF2]{coreide230.bpl} ProjectModule.TBaseProject.EditProjectOptions (Line 1135, "ProjectModule.pas" + 2) + $53
[20611ECD]{coreide230.bpl} ProjectModule.TCustomCodeIProject.EditProjectOptions (Line 2330, "ProjectModule.pas" + 0) + $1
[207103C5]{coreide230.bpl} Containers.TStdProjectContainer.SaveProject (Line 2404, "Containers.pas" + 3) + $0
[2070F620]{coreide230.bpl} Containers.TStdProjectContainer.CommandHandler (Line 2240, "Containers.pas" + 14) + $6
[204D07EF]{coreide230.bpl} ContainerIntf.TIDEProjectManagerMenuObject.Execute (Line 862, "ContainerIntf.pas" + 26) + $17
[204D2412]{coreide230.bpl} ContainerIntf.TProjectManagerMenuItem.Click (Line 1110, "ContainerIntf.pas" + 18) + $22
[50AC2300]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Menus.TMenu.DispatchCommand (Line 3461, "Vcl.Menus.pas" + 5) + $4
[50AC3572]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Menus.TPopupList.WndProc (Line 4622, "Vcl.Menus.pas" + 4) + $E
[50AC34C1]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Menus.TPopupList.MainWndProc (Line 4597, "Vcl.Menus.pas" + 2) + $5
[50172214]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 16886, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[5098DEDA]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.ObjectFromHWnd (Line 3555, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 4) + $A
[50ADDEDD]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.CancelHint (Line 11272, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 6) + $D
[50ADCB6F]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10443, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[50ADCBB2]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10473, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50ADCEE5]{vcl230.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10611, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

Comment: Clearly the IDE has a bug in it.  It is accessing a nil pointer.  Have you filed a bug report in [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com) yet?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i have not. I was hoping that someone had already had this issue and had a workaround/solution. Will create one now. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use the `Project` menu in the IDE's top menu bar, instead of clicking on the project in the Project Manager?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I started using the menu option after you asked. It eventually did happen going through the menu option as well.

Comment: I HAVE EXACTLY THE SAME ISSUE TOO! Delphi XE7. Win 7. Disabling CnPack and GExperts won't help. In my case, I can use the Project Options after I restart Delphi. But after using the IDE a while, I can't anymore.

Comment: @mwhobrey Do you have any solution? –

Comment: @Rigel no I do not. I filed a bug with Emb iirc. It is still happening to me on 10.2 and the only way around it is to shut down the IDE and start it back up and go into the project options before doing anything else.

Comment: I don't report bugs anymore to Emba because it results on one of these: 1) the bug is not fixed or 2) the bugs is fixed after some years. Meanwhile I loose the ability to upgrade to the version that has the bug fixed so basically I pay to have a bug fixed (after I reported the bug anyway).

Comment: I started porting my code to Lazarus now. In 2 hours I already ported 6 units. But it is getting faster as I learn. The documentation about how to migrate is scattered in multiple placed. And the Delphi to Lazarus wizard is not great. However, questions asked on the forum are answered in minutes (I wish it would have been the same with Emba support). And I realized there is another cool thing with Lazarus: when you reinstall your Windows, you don't wait for days until Emba will issue a new key for you.